# Working with Static Class members in C++

Tags: c++, static

I just started learning C++, using the original book by Bjarne Stroustrap. The book, in its chapter about Clases, has an example of creating a Date class that has the following interface:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Date
{
public: //public interface:
    typedef
    enum Month{Jan=1, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec}
    Month;

    class Bad_date{ };  //exception class

    Date(int dd = 0, int mm = 1, int yy = 0);
    Date(int dd = 0, Month mm =Month(0), int yy =0); 
    //functions for examining the Date:
    int day() const;
    Month month() const;
    int year() const;
    std::string string_rep() const;     //string representation
    void char_rep(char s[]) const;      //C-style string representation

    static void set_default(int, Month, int);
    static Date default_date;
    //functions for changing the Date:
    Date& add_year(int n);          //add n years
    Date& add_month(int n);         //add n months
    Date& add_day(int n);           //add n days
private:
    int d, m, y;                //representation
    bool leapyear(int n);       //check if year is a leapyear. 
};
```

I need help understanding how the static member in this class, `static Date default_date` works. In my method implementations, I use the variable, such as in my first few lines of the constructor

```
Date::Date(int dd, Month mm, int yy)
{

if(yy == 0)
    yy = default_date.year();
if(iNt mm == 0)
    mm = default_date.month();
if(dd == 0)
    dd = default_date.day();
        .
        .
        .
 }
```

When I call the constructor, I get an `undefined reference to 'Date::default_date'` error while compiling. I read online that this is usually caused when a static variable is unitialized, so I tried that by declaring the variable as:

```
static Date default_date = 0; //or
static Date default_date = NULL;
```

either of these declarations don't work, and they both give me another error

```
invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'Date'
'Date Date::default_date' has incomplete type
```

How do I deal with this error?
Thanks.

Comment: define them outside the class - `Date Date::default_date;` in a single implementation file.

Comment: "Stroustrap ... Clases ..."  ... Snort.

Comment: Also http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/link-errs-static-data-mems.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *define* the variable this way:

```
Date Date::default_date(1, 1, 1980);
```

And you should put it in a `.cpp` file, not the `.h` one, because it is a definition, and if it where included in a header file you could get it defined multiple times.

Comment: Instead of doing exactly that, I did `static Date default_date(1,1,92)`. That worked fine too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `static` keyword from the implementation in the .cpp file and avoid initialising it to `0`:

Date.cpp:

```
Date Date::default_date(1, 1, 1970);
```

Comment: The whole point of this question is that the member is `static`.

Comment: @Alnitak I don't understand what you mean; you use `static` in the *declaration* of a static member variable, but not in the *definition*.

Answer (score 0):

first， if you should the default constructor，`static Date default_date;` will be ok.

second, you should initialize the object default_date, `Date Date::default_date(1, 1, 1980);`

Answer (score -1):

```
// header
struct wtf{};
struct omg{ static wtf lol; /* declaration of lol */ };
// cpp
wtf omg::lol; // definition of lol

int main(){ omg().lol; /* test if you can instantiate omg and access lol */ }
```

Comment: @stefan I have it all explained in comments.

Comment: [@stefan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/985296/stefan) comments are the ones after // and in between /* */